# How can we deploy smart contract, its front end and backend server based on Mongodb to Rinkeby

Tags: contract-deployment, dapp-development

I have designed a dapp (based on nodeJS and Mongodb) which uses IPFS, Oraclize, a front end and off chain Mongodb server (based on mLab). Till now I was using Ganache for all local testing and development. Now I have to launch this dapp on Rinkeby network and make front-end and backend available to users. What is the preferred way/platform for such kind of dapp deployments which can be done easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Etherlime](https://github.com/LimeChain/etherlime). Easy to install and use. Just a few lines of codes are needed.

```
const deployer = new etherlime.InfuraPrivateKeyDeployer('Your Private Key Goes Here', 'ropsten', 'Your Infura API Key', defaultConfigs);

const result = await deployer.deploy(TestContract, '0xda8a06f1c910cab18ad187be1faa2b8606c2ec86', 1539426974);
```

You can find more info and documentation in their [github](https://github.com/LimeChain/etherlime).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to deploy a smart contract on any of the different networks. Your best bet is to look into the different methods and choose which one is best for you.

[This](https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/dev-highlights-of-this-week-cb33e58c745f) guide explains how to deploy the contract on Rinkeby via Geth. It is a little more involved than other ways, but also allows you to have the most power and flexibility when doing so.

[This](https://medium.com/swlh/deploy-smart-contracts-on-ropsten-testnet-through-ethereum-remix-233cd1494b4b) guide explains how to deploy a contract on Ropsten using [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and Metamask. This is another very common way to deploy a contract, but gives slightly less flexibility.

My suggestion is to try a few different deployment methods (CLI, MetaMask, Geth, Parity, etc.) and see which you like best. You will also learn how deployments and other Ethereum related actions work by using all these tools.